# Minimum number of steps to reduce a number to zero.

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to solve a problem which is described below:

> Given a number $n$, reduce it to $0$ in a minimum number of steps using the $2$ operations below:
>
> 1. $n$ can be changed to $\max (a,b)$, where $n=a\cdot b$ ($a$ and $b$ can't be $1$ or $n$ and they have not specified anything about the factors).
> 2. $n$ can be decremented by $1$.
>    The minimum number of steps has to be reported.

My strategy to solve this is as follows:
Continue till $n$ is reduced to $0$:

If $n$ is not a prime number then find a factor of $n$ starting from $\sqrt{n}$ to $0$. Divide $n$ with this factor, this new value is the reduced $n$.

 If $n$ is a prime number then decrement it by $1$.
But this strategy fails for many inputs like $214567$. Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what happens when $n=214567$?

Comment: @LeeMosher My strategy gives the following sequence: 214567,491,490,35,7,6,3,2,1,0 ( 9 steps) whereas the expected answer is 8 steps.

Comment: In step 1, is $ab=n$ or not?

Comment: yes it is ,I will edit the question to indicate that,thanks.

Comment: And do you know what the 8 steps are for the "expected answer"?

Comment: Certainly there is a naive dynamic programming algorithm that solves this, but what are you looking for?

Comment: No,the solution said breadth-first search was to be used to calculate the answer. I couldn't actually understand what it were trying to do.

Comment: @par I am looking for a greedy strategy which can help me solve it. And could you please provide me any reference to the algorithm you mentioned.

Comment: Graph search: start at $n$. Let $\{n_1,\ldots,n_N\}$ be all possible values that you get from *any* one step (e.g., $n_1=n-1$). Solve the problem for all of these values. Pick the minimum. Breadth-first just refers to the order in which each of these nodes are checked. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: @par OfCourse, normal recursion would not work we need to find a way to reuse the previously calculated values,if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Your algorithm is simply not optimal.

Comment: @z100 What would be an optimal strategy, if you could please suggest?

Comment: see this: 214567, 21466, 2, 1, 0 (4 steps).

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question : n can be reduced to max(a,b) where n=a*b and(a and b are not equal to 1 and n)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Hovewer there is no guarantee that the smallest possible value is the best choice for next step. Good example is the start value of $2^n+1$

Comment: So,the only way is to try all possible combinations?But how do i do that efficiently?

Comment: @KishanKishore: use a graph search and make sure to not do any repeated computation (i.e. store the optimal number of steps for any node you visit). P.s. - this question is probably more appropriate for cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: When is decrementing by one better than halving? Other than primes, the first numbers this is true are: 33 (6 steps) ,46 (6 steps), and 58 (7 steps). so 33= 3*11=1+(4)(2*2*2); 46 =  2*(1+(2*11)) = 1 + 5(3*3). Calling this race to 2, will simplify by a few steps, because then you don't have to write 2->1->0 every time. (or You could call it race to less than 5 and skip (3 or 4) ->2->1->0). 11,14,19,22 = slow. 8,9,12,16, = fast.

Comment: You are using a greedy algorithm.  It reduces the number as much as possible at the current step.  What you are finding is that the greedy algorithm is not optimal because some larger numbers are faster than some smaller numbers.